# UINavigationController shows black screen after pushing a view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a storyboard application with a navigation controller an two views controllers ('A', 'B').

In the Storyboard file:
Navigationcontroller is the initial view controller. view controller 'A' is connected to the Navigationcontroller as rootcontroller. View controller 'B' is in storyboard but not connected to any view controller.

when i programmatically try to push view controller 'B' onto the navigationcontroller from inside view controller 'A' with:

```
B *controllerB = [[B alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controllerB animated:YES];
```

all i get is a transition to a black screen.

i checked the navigationController property in view controller A at runtime and it´s not nil. 
I do not instantiate the navigationController by myself, I let storyboard do the work (maybe that´s the problem). But I think it should be possible to "manually" push view controller to a navigation controller created by storyboard.

When I connect a segue from a button to 'B' in storyboard everything works fine. 
Only programmatically it does not work, only shows a black screen inside the navigationcontroller.

Maybe someone could help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. I was already using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` to navigate to view controller in different storyboard. I am using xcode7.2 and Swift.

I am navigating from storyboard1, some view controller's button action.
Destination is to initial Navigation controller of Storyboard2.
Still I get black screen.

The problem was storyboard2's Navigation controller linked to 1st view controller was linked via `show`.

**Solution:**
Delete the link between Nav controller and 1st view controller. Now link it using `root view controller`. (Ctrl+Click on Navigation controller and drag it to the View controller and Select the option "root view controller")

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used storyboards yet so this answer is from a glance at the docs. It looks like you can't alloc/init a view controller from a storyboard. You need to use the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` method of your `UIStoryboard` instance and then you can push the controller.