# why use storyboard push a viewcontroller shows black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I created a SingleView application then use "Embed In Navigation Controller" to get a navigation control.
when push a controller, the viewcontroller's backgroundColor is black.

i know use this code :

```
UIStoryboard * storyBoard  =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];//UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
UIViewController *roomController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"controlerID"];
```

but what's the reason  ?
and if i don't want to use the storyboard completely ,only use this code

```
 UIViewController *roomController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
```

what can i do?  is only set the viewcontroller's backgroundColor?

Comment: can you show your `controlerID` name in scene

Comment: try this UIViewController *roomController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"NibNa`me" bundle: nil]

Comment: Just allocating with init won't really instantiate your view controller. Either you have to get it from initWithNibName or using storyboard identifier

Comment: Can you show you you present the VC? performSegue?Push?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UINavigationController shows black screen after pushing a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260712/uinavigationcontroller-shows-black-screen-after-pushing-a-view)

Comment: hi @Anbu.Karthik  I am really sorry for the late reply.i only want to know why  would  this problem  exist that the code "[[UIViewController alloc]init]"

Comment: hi @KKRocks   I am really sorry for the late reply.your  Method is ok。 but i only want to know why  would  this problem  exist that the code "[[UIViewController alloc]init]"。

Comment: hi @SivajeeBattina  I am really sorry for the late reply. can you tell me some detail'Article for you tell me.why won't really instantiate? thank you very much!

Comment: @SeanLintern88 I am really sorry for the late reply.i use push the viewController!

Comment: hi @SargisGevorgyan I am really sorry for the late reply.you are right.But  i only want to know why would this problem exist that the code "[[UIViewController alloc]init]".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`: method of your `UIStoryboard` instance and then you can push the controller.

Comment: I am really sorry for the late reply.yes you are right,too。but the new viewController is't UIStoryboard or xib。and  i'm only want to konw the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *roomController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"controlerID"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: roomController animated:YES];
```

**// if You make controller  with out storyboard Than change You view color**

```
UIViewController *roomController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: roomController animated:YES];

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  self.view.backgroundColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Comment: I am really sorry for the late reply.yes you are right。i'm deal with this problem like you。but i'm only want to konw the reason.